# HTML/CSS -- boxes side by side within box

Tags: html, css

I  am trying to build some boxes side by side within a box. following is the design. can someone help me with the html/css for this.

[image]

Comment: What's your HTML code, what CSS have you tried? Where did you get stuck? At a minimum the picture you show has some implied HTML, have you made any attempts at converting that into a HTML structure you could start experimenting with?

Comment: I am trying to add my html/css but it always throws an error saying "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." I added what i am trying to do but still does not let me post it.

Comment: Post the bare minimum so we can get at least the idea what steps you took. Per instance post how you structured html frames for a pair of boxes and post css for that single frame. After that you can add a picture of your result. That shouldn't be too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you're looking for?

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
}

article {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.centre {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.float-left {
  float: left;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<article class="centre">
  <div class="float-left"></div>
  <div class="float-right"></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</article>
<article class="float-left">
  <div class="float-left"></div>
  <div class="float-right"></div>
</article>
<article class="float-right">
  <div class="float-left"></div>
  <div class="float-right"></div>
</article>
<div class="clear"></div>
<article class="centre">
  <div class="float-left"></div>
  <div class="float-right"></div>
</article>
```

Another option would also be to use absolute positioning if you don't need your webpage to be responsive.

Comment: This helped me a lot, thank you very much!